# I'm looking for a JSON file in a web stream to use with selenieum in python to scrape all the review text

Tags: json, web-scraping, steam

I'm looking for a JSON file in a web stream to use with selenieum in python to scrape all the review text plese help me (I'm not good at languages ​​and use google translate.)

Comment: What do you mean with the "to scrape all the review text"? Do you want an example JSON stream? or what do you want specifically.

Comment: My teacher said that these websites will tick all the data in the JSON file. And she let me find it but I can't find it

Comment: Is that what youre looking for? Thats a sample api where you can test your webscraper library.... [Sample API Request](https://tools.learningcontainer.com/sample-json.json)